Which is the correct way to access Application class nowadays?
In the codelabs of modern android developers, they showed this way:
class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var container: AppContainer
    lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        container = AppContainer()
        context = applicationContext
    }
}

fun CreationExtras.CustomApplication(): CustomApplication=
    (this[ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY] as CustomApplication)

And access this way: CustomApplication().context
But it is giving me null in context, becuase onCreate is not being called for some reason. Another Android dev tell me that he things that code from the codelabs is wrong, and that it's creating new instances of application each time you are calling it. He told me to do it this way:
class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var container: AppContainer
    lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        container = AppContainer()
        context = applicationContext
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: CustomApplication
    }
}

And access this way: CustomApplication.instance.context
And it's working, but I'm not sure this is the correct way to use singleton pattern on Application class.. and also the IDE is giving me a warning on the instance variable:

Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
reference to CustomApplication which has field context pointing to
Context); this is a memory leak

Which is the best way to access Application class nowadays?

Inject it via your dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.). Otherwise, call getApplicationContext() on whatever other Context you have. "But it is giving me null in context, becuase onCreate is not being called for some reason" -- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ov18d2/this_is_why_your_subclassed_application_isnt/

Yes, you must never call an Application or Activity constructor yourself. It makes no sense at all and will give you an obviously invalid Context. What is the point of your context property in your Application class since it does nothing but duplicate the existing applicationContext property? And why does the app container need to be lateinit instead of just a val instantiated at the declaration site?

@CommonsWare, I think in OP’s case, onCreate() isn’t called because they literally just called the application class’s constructor and tried to use that instance. But regarding the issue you linked, the solution if you do need auto backups is that you need to do a safe cast of the application context and fallback to not using it in any broadcast receivers and services not started within activitities?

If you are referring to container = AppContainer(), the custom Application is CustomApplication. I do not know what AppContainer is. "you need to do a safe cast of the application context and fallback to not using it in any broadcast receivers and services not started within activitities" -- pretty much, yes. getApplicationContext() returns Context!, and in this case we know of cases where it could be null, so safe calls and the like will be needed.

@CommonsWare, I was referring to this quote from above: “And access this way: CustomApplication().context”

Ah, OK, I see! I suspect that's just a typo in the question -- the second example (CustomApplication.instance.context) doesn't use the constructor.

This might be a matter of code taste but for me, the cleanest way is to inject the Application instance with Dagger Hilt when needed.
you can see a detailed example here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android
